# Using alias in query to get sum

Tags: mysql

I am using alias in another parameter to get cumulative sum but getting error. How to put alias in query.

```
SET @total=0;
SET @amountDue=0;

SELECT cs.customer_name,l.paid_date, IF(@total=0,((pl.total_amount)-
(pl.installment_amount_month)*( pl.total_installments))
,( pl.installment_amount_month)) AS AmountDue
      ,@amountDue := @amountDue + AmountDue as ComulativeDue,

 l.amount AS AmountPaid,
  @total := @total +l.amount AS comulativePaid,
 (@total/@amountDue ) as percentage
 FROM payments_details l join payment_loan pl on (pl.loan_id=l.loan_id) join
 customer cs on (cs.customer_id=l.customer_id)
 WHERE l.customer_id=cs.customer_id and pl.loan_id=l.loan_id
 GROUP BY l.paid_date ORDER BY  l.paid_date ;
```

Comment: Well what is the error?

Comment: i am adding @amountDue + alias name of AmountDue

Comment: No. What is the exact error that you're getting?

Comment: Error is unknown column AmountDue

Answer (score 0):

No you can't directly use the column alias like that unless you are trying to access it in a outer select query. You will have to use the entire expression to calculate `AmoutnDue` rather like

```
SELECT cs.customer_name,l.paid_date, IF(@total=0,((pl.total_amount)-
(pl.installment_amount_month)*( pl.total_installments))
,( pl.installment_amount_month)) AS AmountDue
      ,@amountDue := @amountDue + IF(@total=0,((pl.total_amount)-
(pl.installment_amount_month)*( pl.total_installments))
,( pl.installment_amount_month)) as ComulativeDue,
```

Comment: i tried this one but my expected result in not correct

Comment: @UserKh, that I am not sure about what calculation you are doing but the point here is, use the entire expression for calculating `AmountDue` in your `CumulativeDue`